# Cannot use jpenable

Tags: jprofiler

I am stuck at square one of trying to profile my app using JProfiler. I am trying to use "jpenable" on RHEL6, but when I select my VM, it simply crashes to the desktop as follows:

```
Please select the profiling mode:
GUI mode (attach with JProfiler GUI) [1, Enter]
Offline mode (use config file to set profiling settings) [2]
1
Please enter a profiling port
[31757]

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.setSchema(Ljavax/xml/validation/Schema;)V
    at org.jdom2.input.sax.XMLReaders.<init>(XMLReaders.java:124)
    at org.jdom2.input.sax.XMLReaders.<clinit>(XMLReaders.java:95)
    at org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder.<init>(SAXBuilder.java:338)
    at org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder.<init>(SAXBuilder.java:221)
    at com.jprofiler.a.h.a(ejt:500)
    <snip so StackOverflow allows the post>
    at com.jprofiler.a.i.g.a(ejt:38)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.attach.c.a(ejt:243)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.EnableApplication.a(ejt:118)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.EnableApplication.g(ejt:81)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.EnableApplication.main(ejt:238)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.Launcher.main(Unknown Source)
```

Any suggestions on what to do? I installed JProfiler 8.0.5 (the current version) from the RPM and simply entered the jpenable command. Everything else is shown above. This is a rather old RHEL6 image, but I cannot upgrade to a more recent one.

I am at a loss for what to try next.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

This is because of a conflicting version of one of the following files

```
xml-apis.jar
xmlParserAPIs.jar
xercesImpl-x.x.x.jar
jaxp-api.jar
```

in the extension directory (`$JAVA_HOME/lib/ext`) of the JRE. You would have to remove that file.